# ES6/7 equivalent to underscore’s range function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, ecmascript-2016

Is there any ECMAScript 6/7 equivalent to underscore’s `range` function?

In underscore:

```
_.range(startPage, endPage + 1);
```

In ES2015:

```
Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => x + i)
```

Not sure how the ES2015 version works. I would like to know how range in ecmascript of javascript works

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you looking for an ES6 version of `range`? Are you asking for clarification on how the second snippet works? If so, what precisely do you not understand about it? At least try to make an attempt at explaining it yourself.

Comment: I would like to know how range in ecmascript of javascript works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is to create an array of length `end - start + 1`, and then fill it with the relevant numbers using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.

In this case Array#from needs an object with the length property. Using `Array(n)` creates such an object (array). You can also use `{ length: n }` directly. In this case `n = Math.abs(end - start) + 1`.

Array#from accepts a `mapFn` callback, a function that can transform the iterated value. The function receives 2 params - the values (which we can ignore in this case), and the index (0 based). Adding `start` to the current index will create the numbers in the range.

```js
const range = (start, end) => Array.from(
  Array(Math.abs(end - start) + 1), 
  (_, i) => start + i
);

console.log(range(5, 10));
console.log(range(-10, -5));
console.log(range(-5, 10));
```

This version will handle reverse range as well (large to small) as well:

```js
const range = (start, end) => {
  const inc = (end - start) / Math.abs(end - start);
  
  return Array.from(
    Array(Math.abs(end - start) + 1), 
    (_, i) => start + i * inc
  );
};

console.log(range(5, 10));
console.log(range(-5, -10));
console.log(range(10, -5));
```

Comment: Another approach would be `(start, end) => new Array(end-start+1).fill().map((_, i) => start + i)`. Not sure which one wins out here.

Comment: A dubious [microbenchmark](https://jsperf.com/array-fill-vs-array-from/1) suggests `Array.fill` is better (on my browser, on Wednesdays, when it's 7C out, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the following implementation does not allow for lazy-generated lists:

```js
Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => x + i)
```

Imagine that you need a list of 1M numbers:

```js
range(1, 1000000);
```

Are you going to consume all of them? Maybe not, yet all the numbers have been generated already and they probably left a non-trivial footprint on your memory.

It would be nice if we could get them one by one on demand.

It turns out we can do exactly that with a generator:

```js
function* range(start, end, step = 1) {
  for (let value = start; value < end; value += step) {
    yield value;
  }
}

for (let x of range(1, Infinity)) {
  if (x > 10) {
    break;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

Did you notice the `range(1, Infinity)` bit?

In a classic implementation where all the numbers are generated in advance, this code wouldn't even run as you would get stuck in an infinite number-generating loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the `range` method generates an array of numbers starting from `start`, stepping with `step` (default = 1) until `end`. This simple function does just that :-)

```js
const range = (start, end, step = 1) => {
  let result = [];
  for(let i=0; i<=end; i+=step) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
};
```

What is nice here is that you can use decimal step values.

For example:

```js
range(0, 2, 0.5) // [ 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 ]
range(0,100,20) // [ 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 ]
```